# Set lc_time_names globally on laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm trying to get a query localized (monthnames) in laravel and I'm having trouble as I don't know how to start.

I know I can `SET lc_time_names = 'es_ES'` as a query before the main query; and all subsequent queries would be localized, but that isn't happening, It always returns the default locale.
Honestly, I don't know if this is the coirrect way of doing this.

Can I use an `App::before` filter to globally set the `lc_time_names`? Or does laravel have an option for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set it in `App::before()` like this:

```
App::before(function($request)
{
    DB::statement("SET lc_time_names = 'es_ES'");
});
```

Comment: where do you add this line?

Comment: where to add this?

Comment: you can try adding it to the boot() method of the AppServiceProvider.php